# How to disable strict mode in mysql using MAMP on a mac

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have spent hours trying to figure this out but am seriously stuck. I installed the latest version of mysql today and some things in my website broke. I believe it has to do with strict settings, IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

I am trying to disable strict mode just to get my site working but it seems impossible. I have tried this in terminal but no luck.

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/conf.d/disable_mysql_strict_mode.cnf


[mysqld] 
    sql_mode="IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

I have looked in every etc folder I can find and other various folders but can't see anything that resembles a .cnf file.

I can do it temporarily through phpmyadmin but if I close MAMP or restart my computer I have to do it again as the change isn't permanent.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### MAMP Pro

1. Open MAMP Pro and check your Settings (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>). Make sure **`Hide Dock Icon` is unchecked**. If required, uncheck the icon, quit MAMP and restart it.
   *Note: This is required to see the menu entries for MAMP. You can hide the Dock Icon again later.*
2. Open the main window of MAMP Pro and via the menu go to **`File > Edit Templates > MySQL > (your version)`**.
   This opens a text editor with your MySQL configuration.
3. In the configuration file **look for the line `[mysqld]`** (note the `d` at the end!).
   Right after this line, add a new line with the following text: `sql_mode=""`
4. Save the file, close it and restart your MySQL server.

[image: MAMP Pro configuration]

---

### MAMP (free)

By default MAMP free starts the MySQL server without a `my.cnf` file, i.e. it uses the default configuration which comes with the MySQL build. So you have to create a config file manually:

1. **Quit MAMP** (stop the servers)
2. Run following **command in the terminal** - it will open the config file inside your text editor app:
   `touch /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf && open -t /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf`
3. When the file is empty, then **add the following content**:

   ```
   [mysqld]
   sql_mode=""
   ```

   *(When the file is not empty, then simply add the line `sql_mode=""` right after the line `[mysqld]`)*
4. **Save** the config file and close the text editor; **restart MAMP** and start the servers.

[image: MAMP free configuration]

Comment: @user8463989 Thanks for the feedback! I have updated the answer to give instructions for MAMP free as well. Let me know, if it worked (I do not have the free version to test it right now)

Comment: Unfortunately, MAMP, starting with MySQL 7.x, for security reasons, is containing my.cnf and is saying that this type of configuration is not supported, and unfortunately it keeps the default sql_mode, or what you can do is to create a procedure for every time you connect to mysql he configure or sql_mode the way you consult.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.x, try the following:

```
SET PERSIST SQL_MODE = "IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION";
```

Comment: Did you run it as a command? Run it like you would run a select, insert or any other command.

If that doesn't work, what is the error?

Comment: Seems like all I had to do was this `[mysqld]
sql_mode=""` but when I had it all on one line it didn't work. As soon as I had it on separate lines it worked

Answer (score 1):

Trying to find and edit the right my.cnf file can be the wrong strategy. For me the critical information from the MAMP PRO guide was:

> You cannot edit my.cnf directly. You
>   must use the MAMP PRO interface to edit your my.cnf file. In the menu
>   go to File > Edit Template > MySQL > my.cnf.

Answer (score 1):

For Free Mamp

Go to PhpMyAdmin > Variables Tabs 
Find **sql mode** line and click on **edit** button
Replace the value with this "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this for the free version of MAMP 5, I found that MAMP will ignore a my.cnf file placed in the /Applications/MAMP/conf/ directory if the permissions are not set correctly. I ran this command to find that out...
`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --verbose --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"`

Which told me this.

mysql: [Warning] World-writable config file '/Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf' is ignored.
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

Doing
 `chmod 755 my.cnf`

Set it right.

Answer (score 0):

On the free version of MAMP,

1. Stop the MAMP server if it's running
2. Open the Terminal app
3. Paste the following:

touch /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf && open -t /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf

4. In the my.cnf window paste the following:

[mysqld]
sql_mode=""

5. Restart MAMP server