# MAMP 5 how to turn off MySQL strict mode?

Tags: mysql, mamp, mamp-pro

In MAMP 5 MySQL 5.7 has strict mode on by default
I did find a couple of solution that disable strict mode until I restart MAMP ( PRO ) but nothing permanent

[Error in mysql when setting default value for DATE or DATETIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374335/error-in-mysql-when-setting-default-value-for-date-or-datetime/36374690#36374690)

Ho can I turn it off?

Comment: Not an answer, but may we ask why you want to disable strict mode in MySQL?

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881773/how-to-turn-on-off-mysql-strict-mode-in-localhost-xampp) should cover what you want.  One option is to edit your `my.cnf` file and turn off strict mode there.  MySQL should read that file each time it starts up (I think).

Comment: I want to turn off strict mode because I have some data field that are populated from an other DB with dates as "0000-00-00" and this is not allowed. Adding in my conf file: [mysqld] sql_mode= seems to work.

Comment: This is the correct answer for MAMP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54311205/313501 - note that the official "duplicate link" points to a XAMPP config answer, which does not work for MAMP